# Kernel missing after update, reappears after using Live USB

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, kernel, updates

I run 12.04 on a ASUS laptop that's about 3+ years old, that has a bad battery. (Requires constant AC power.)

I recently did an update that included a kernel. I ran the update and rebooted, and for some reason , grub couldn't find the kernel, and I was stuck there for awhile. Being a relatively inexperienced Linux user, I decided to load my live USB, copy over files I wanted to keep, and reinstall. Mid-copy , I bumped my power cable and unplugged the computer. When I booted back up, it loaded my hard disk install without problem.

Why did this happen in the first place, what fixed it, and how can I avoid this problem in the future?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the install hadn't completed properly for some reason: specifically it had not updated the grub configuration to change the boot options.

This does not explain what fixed the problem, but it seem likely that a subsequent update finished the process. You could have run update grub to get it to update the list of kernels:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your kernel list.

Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type this command :

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

Now check your current kernel:

```
uname -r
```

Update your grub to make your newest kernel on the list.

```
sudo update-grub
```